# How do I make a div animation slide up and disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I know this may sound like a basic question but the truth is I'm not that of an expert with animations and it's hard to calculate the math from x and y. So, I would like to know how to make the "gl_banner" div simply slide up after a 0.5-1 second(s) and disappear and the content below it will be pushed up to its original position. What css properties do I use? css-animation? transition? How do I do it?

P.S. I did some research on animations and I saw a lot of animations, advanced animations but couldn't find a simple slide up animation. A little help is appreciated! Thanks!

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="gl_banner" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">Good Luck! :)</div>
                <form id="quiz" action="grade.php" method="post" style="visibility:hidden;">
                    <!--Question 1-->
                    <h3>1. How many percent of modern camera phones use CMOS?</h3>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-A">A) 20%</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-B" value="B" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-B">B) 80%</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-C" value="C" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-C">C) 50%</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-D" value="D" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-D">D) 90%</label>
                    </div>
                    <!--Question 2-->
                    <h3>2. Which type of camera setting(s) is best for greater control and flexibility in terms of focusing on a subject?</h3>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-A" value="A" />
                        <label for="question-2-answers-A">A) Manual Focus</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-B" value="B" />
                        <label for="question-2-answers-B">B) Auto Focus</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-C" value="C" />
                        <label for="question-2-answers-C">C) Both A and B</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-D" value="D" />
                        <label for="question-2-answers-D">D) Neither</label>
                    </div>
                    <!--Question 3-->
                    <h3>3. What are the three properties included in an exposure triangle?</h3>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-A" value="A" />
                        <label for="question-3-answers-A">A) White Balance, ISO, Low Light</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-B" value="B" />
                        <label for="question-3-answers-B">B) Shutter Speed, Exposure, ISO</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-C" value="C" />
                        <label for="question-3-answers-C">C) Aperture, ISO, Exposure</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-D" value="D" />
                        <label for="question-3-answers-D">D) ISO, Aperture, Shutter Speed</label>
                    </div>
                    <!--Question 4-->
                    <h3>4. The higher the ISO, the more noise it produces in an image.</h3>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-A" value="A" />
                        <label for="question-4-answers-A">A) True</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-4-answers" id="question-4-answers-B" value="B" />
                        <label for="question-4-answers-B">B) False</label>
                    </div>
                    <!--Question 5-->
                    <h3>5. What is the name of the smartphone you've seen all over this site?</h3>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-A" value="A" />
                        <label for="question-5-answers-A">A) Nokia Pureview 808</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-B" value="B" />
                        <label for="question-5-answers-B">B) Nokia Lumia 1020</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-C" value="C" />
                        <label for="question-5-answers-C">C) Nokia Lumia 925</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-5-answers" id="question-5-answers-D" value="D" />
                        <label for="question-5-answers-D">D) Nokia Lumia 920</label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <hr style="border-top:1px; border-style:solid; border-color: #000;" />
                    <input style="cursor:pointer;" type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
                </form>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function takeQuiz()
{
// hide the intro
document.getElementById('intro').style.display = 'none';

// display the quiz
document.getElementById('quiz').style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById('gl_banner').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('gl_banner').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery library .
Ex:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

$( "intro" ).hide(); //hide div "intro" immd 
$( "intro" ).click(function( event ) {//hide div "intro" on click 
  event.preventDefault();
  $( this ).hide();
});

$( "intro" ).show(); //to show after hide

$( "intro" ).fadeOut();
$( "intro" ).fadeIn();
```

Comment: i dont know anything about jquery. I just want a simple javascript code without the use of libraries.

Comment: Just add this script include line within the <head> section , and follow the exact syntax. Very simple !

Comment: Just by reading it, it does the exact same thing as my javascript code. What I want changed now is the "gl_banner" div to slide up animated and disappear, that's it.

Comment: use $("gl_banner").fadeout();

Comment: Um, I'm having trouble running the jquery code now. I added mine after your comment to include mine. Is that correct?

Comment: jquery script in head at the top .

Comment: At the bottom put the code I put into <script> //here </script>

Comment: i believe i have done that shown above? mind editing the code, so I know what you mean.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot edit already posted answers too much . They anyway get declined.

Comment: okay, I'll try to figure it out. Thanks for giving me a head start.

Answer (score 0):

Check an example made by me with `click` function from JQuery:

[Knee's Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaptKnee/9WJhy/)

---

Have fun (: